# Profile picture disappeared

Tags: support, profile-picture

Some profile pictures don't show up: on the top bar, on profile pages and on the page with questions. I have checked my ad blocker settings, but there is nothing that blocks the images. Gravatar profile pictures work fine, but other ones don't. I also can't access [my profile picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCodV.png) directly, it just shows a blank page. I'm using Firefox, but it also doesn't show up in other browsers. I'm not using a proxy. Also, if I load a page for the first time, then the pictures still show up. If I refresh, they are gone and they don't come back.

Some profiles where the picture doesn't show up:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/229438/programfox
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/180276/doorknob
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/255622/user124548
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/213480/bigood

I've used [web-sniffer.net](http://web-sniffer.net/) to check the headers of the response, and it returns this:

```
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx    
Date:   Mon, 17 Mar 2014 18:23:46 GMT   
Content-Type:   image/png   
Content-Length: 4126    
Connection: close   
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=deddc4d3b08f0d8d6b685be78cc72f1261395080626160; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.imgur.com; HttpOnly 
Cache-Control:  public, max-age=315360000   
ETag:   "34fad3333e8ab3037860c039558f4612"  
Expires:    Thu, 14 Mar 2024 18:23:46 GMT   
Last-Modified:  Fri, 30 Aug 2013 07:39:12 GMT   
x-amz-version-id:   2zOZXzTnINAw.kaAXl5d3Pkvbearr7pr    
CF-Cache-Status:    MISS    
Vary:   Accept-Encoding 
CF-RAY: 10cb39398ca508b1-FRA
```

Is it just me or is this a bug?

[EDIT]

Now all works fine again. I don't know the reason, but probably it was just a temporary problem on my computer.

Comment: Just you, it looks like. Either Gravatar or i.stack.imgr.com is blocked on your end. Does your own profile image work? Does https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/24780fb6df85a943c7aea0402c843737?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't think they are blocked. I have checked my ad blockers, but I'll check them again. My own profile picture does not work, but I can access that Gravatar link.

Comment: I meant for you to test the image directly; does my gravatar link load for you?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, your Gravatar link works. But I don't have problems with Gravatar, they show up fine. I'll add that in my question.

Comment: So your own profile image doesn't work? It helps if you give us examples (screenshots, links to profiles) so we can at least determine what the pattern might be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No, because that is uploaded to i.stack.imgur.com, but Adblock Plus shows that it doesn't block i.stack.imgur.com.

Comment: Accessing http://i.stack.imgur.com/iCodV.png  directly doesn't work? This is not necessarily Adblocks fault; I am trying to help you troubleshoot where *else* this goes wrong.

Comment: What browser? Is the problem limited to one browser or is it independent of the used browser?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It doesn't work directly. I've added that in my question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: It's a browser-independent problem.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: So you get no errors, just a blank page? What does a command line tool like `curl` tell you? `curl -D - -o /dev/null http://i.stack.imgur.com/iCodV.png` would try and load the image and print the headers the server returned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've added the headers.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: That is almost exactly the headers I see. But you are getting *blank* images instead? Something is messing up those images. Any chance you can upload one of those images somewhere for us to analyze?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, blank images. And the 'page' source of the image is also blank.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Do you have security software installed? Maybe imgur got blacklisted somewhere on your end.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No proxy. And I'm sure that it is not blacklisted, because the first time I load a page, I see the images. If I refresh, they are gone.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: Only after a refresh your images are blank? In all browsers?

Comment: @ProgramFOX if you browse to http://imgur.com what you see? Can you upload a picture there? If yes, can you later view it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce this issue - all image requests to [Imgur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) are working properly at the moment.

Comment: Now all works fine again.